# tikz-uml "Extra \or. \end{umlcall}" error

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, diagrams

I'm trying to figure out why my freshly installed TexStudio (+ MikTex) cannot find the tikz-uml package.

As a test, I was trying to build the following example (cloned the entire project, so the .sty file is where it is supposed to be):
https://github.com/lebedov/tikzumlx/blob/master/examples/seqdiag.tex

The error I'm getting is `Extra \or. \end{umlcall}`

> ! Extra \or. \ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or
> \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep... l.90 \end{umlcall}
> I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

P.S. On Ubuntu, I can compile the example, so it seems to be windows-related.

---

Minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[no ddots]{B}
\umlobject[x=11,no ddots]{A}
\begin{umlcallself}[op={$\alpha$}]{B}
    \begin{umlcall}[op=$\beta$, type=synchron, dt=4]{B}{A} 
        \begin{umlcall}[op=$\gamma$, type=synchron, dt= 6]{A}{B}
            \begin{umlcallself}[op={$\epsilon$}, dt = 1]{B}
                \begin{umlcallself}[op={$\theta$}, dt = 1]{B}
                \end{umlcallself}
            \end{umlcallself}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}
\end{umlcallself}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ubuntu - works.
Windows:
[image]

```
! Extra \or.
\ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or 
                                        \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep...
l.20            \end{umlcallself}
                         
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \or.
\ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or 
                                        \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep...
l.21        \end{umlcall}
                    
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \or.
\ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or 
                                        \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep...
l.22    \end{umlcall}
                   
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \or.
\ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or 
                                        \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep...
l.23 \end{umlcallself}
                      
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

Comment: don't link to external examples. Add a small but complete example here. And show also the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added an example. It also has tkz-graph (.sty is in the folder).

Comment: well the sty is buggy. It uses `\thetikzumlCallNum` when testing numbers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer which one?

Comment: the tikz-uml.sty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yeah, but unfortunately it's the latest one (v 1.0. from march 2016)

Comment: well open an issue in the github repo. If they correct it, fine, if not better drop it and look for an alternative.

Comment: I'll try github, thanks