# tikz-uml: "Extra \or. \end{umlcall}" -- Issue returned on new tex versions?

Tags: tikz-uml, texlive2022, texlive-2023

Again a problem with tikz-uml causing the `Extra \or. \end{umlcall}` error. However, the solutions from before ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664835/tikz-uml-extra-or-endumlcall-error) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44768/tikz-uml-sequence-diagram-extra-or-error)) didn't help.

It seems that this is a recent change, since I had a project a year ago (using tex version 2021) that worked without problems, although it now started acting up there too.

The example is taken from the [tikz-uml documentation](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf) section 5.3.1 "Basic / recursive calls".

Here is a link to my overleaf project: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tbwmdypsgnmg

The error occurs on

- overleaf with tex version 2021, but can be fixed by adding `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.
- the fix does not work for version 2022.
- I also use Mactex 2023 locally, and have the same issue there too.
- Also, uploads to Arxiv (which supposedly uses tex-live 2023) yield the error.

Any helpful comments welcome, since I'd like to continue using tikz-uml sequence diagrams.

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject [class=A] {a}
\umlobject [class=B] {b}
\umlobject [class=C] {c}
\begin{umlcall}{a}{b}
\begin{umlcall}{b}{c}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.  Copy and paste it, so that we can copy and paste it.

Comment: The code is there, including the link to the Overleaf example. I posted the screenshot to highlight which error was raised and where.

Comment: Hey did you manage to fix your code? I'm stuck just as you are/was. @stklik